# Java threads monitoring\profiling\measurement

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, jvisualvm

I am familiar with

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html

I would like to test\profile\measure how many CPU time did the thread get.
I added the following to the my thread constructor:

```
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().setThreadCpuTimeEnabled(true);
if(!ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported())
    System.err.println("measure is not supported.");
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().setThreadContentionMonitoringEnabled(true);
if(!ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported())
    System.err.println("contention is not supported.");
```

Then when the thread has finished it's execution, I executed:

```
long tID = Thread.currentThread().getId();
long execTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCpuTime(tID);
```

But for most of my threads, which I am **ABSOLUTELY SURE** that they do occupy the CPU, I get execution time of zero (execTime == 0).

How may I measure my threads? What could be the problem in the above procedure?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: have you confirmed via jconsole/visualvm? i use the same as you with no problems, perhaps its down to when you call the method? If you call the same via the jconsole mbean interface, you should see a non-zero number... you can also try getThreadUserTime(id)

Comment: @Toby, thanks for your reply. For most of the threads I receive zero value, not for all of them; so I guess, I call these procedure in the right place in my code. Using JConsole force me not to end the program and connect to it, but the JConsole provided analysis to threads that are in the system (blocked, waiting, running) and not for threads that were terminated. The same idea holds for JVisualVM.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Thread Top](http://www.performize-it.com/tools/thread-top), it's all done, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I get my java process ID from the Java VirtualVM (jvirtualvm) and executing the one of the examples on the ThreadTop website, all I get is exceptions.

Comment: are you trying to google for me?! or provide me with a resolution??

Comment: Both projects do the same thing as you do - and they're not million lines long, so have a look at the source and see how they do it. If you don't like my answers, disregard them, but please show some respect for people who are trying to help you. This is just plain rude. If you want solution brought you on the plate, pay $ for commercial support.

Comment: you try to get your answer count higher by providing tools you have googled and not tried; and speaking of "million lines long", it doesn't seem that my snipped code above hold "million lines". instead of referring me to other implementations which you have never tried, try to explain why the code above isn't good.

Comment: Just to let you know, one of the projects was written by my close colleague. And no, I don't care about my answer count.